# Proper way to create CSS3 Pentagon

Tags: html, css, polygon

Want to get header shape like that. Don't want to use png. I know that there is the way to create triangle:

```
#triangle-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid red;
}
```

But is there proper way to get pentagon like that, for header?
Or only png will help me in this situation?

[image]

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://codepen.io/chipChocolate/pen/myrqXo)?